# button click event in repeater control to show data in same repeater in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a Button inside a repeater on whose click textbox should be visible to user to enter, but i have a list of button and clicking on specific button textbox should open specifically for that button only,

Currently when i click button all the textboxs gets visible to user.

Here Is The Code....

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt">
        <div align="right" id="reply">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnreply" OnClick="lnkbtnreply_Click" Text="Reply"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>

        <asp:TextBox ID=""  placeholder="Enter Your Reply Here" Visible="false">
      </asp:TextBox>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void lnkbtnreply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
       foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptcomment.Items) 
       {
             Panel replypic = (Panel)item.FindControl("replypic");
             Panel replywrite = (Panel)item.FindControl("replywrite");
             replypic.Visible = true; replywrite.Visible = true;
       }
}
```

Comment: this is your desing. where is code part?

Comment: protected void lnkbtnreply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptcomment.Items)
        {Panel replypic = (Panel)item.FindControl("replypic");
            Panel replywrite = (Panel)item.FindControl("replywrite"); replypic.Visible = true;
                    replywrite.Visible = true;}}

Comment: Edit your question with the code, comments are not ment for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Found The Answer. In Case You Guys Are Still Searching For It Have A Look :

Here is the Code Behind:

```
protected void rptcomment_ItemCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Panel replypic = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("replypic");
        Panel replywrite = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("replywrite");
        if (e.CommandName == "img_Click") // check command is cmd_delete
        {
            // get you required value
            string CustomerID = (e.CommandArgument).ToString();
            replypic.Visible = true;
            replywrite.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx Nitin I really Dont know how to edit code here

Comment: Your welcome :) . For further formatting help you can [Read Here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)